# Wolfram Mathematica Functions in Lyx

Tags: math-mode, macros, lyx, wolfram-mathematica

When using LyX, how can I call Mathematica to input a mathematical expression, such as using Mathematica's `Solve[]` function, and return the result directly to LyX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I fear, this question is off-topic, as this site deals with TeX and its features, not with features from Mathematica.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you include more information to your question? If the question is about how to typeset functions in a particular manner, it is perfectly on topic.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Good point. I clicked on a wrong 'duplicate of' suggestion; sorry.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Not necessarily OT, LyX allows you to 'connect to' some computer algebra systems, and thereby using their features directly in a document. (As I understand it, never tried.) I don't know if one can connect to Mathematica though.

Comment: Yes, LyX does support Mathematica. shj: Make a math box in LyX (ctrl + m), put in the math box "solve(...)", and then right-click and go to Use Computer Algebra System and then "Mathematica". If that doesn't work, can you please give a very detailed account of what you have tried and post a LyX minimal example?

Comment: Thank you. I also want to do something like D[Sin[x],x]/.x->3      ; and thinks with Plot[]

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: @scottkosty Hey, can you make your comment into an answer? The same was asked a bit ago on latex-community, so i guess it is helpful for others.

Comment: @Johannes_B I can't add an answer because the question was put on hold

Comment: @scottkosty Sorted

Comment: @scottkosty It would be great, if you could add a sentence or two to the question, to make it a bit better.

Comment: @Johannes_B I edited it to my interpretation and added an answer.

Answer (score 4):

LyX does support Mathematica. Make a math box in LyX (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>), put in the math box `solve(...)`, then right-click and go to `Use Computer Algebra System` and then `Mathematica`.